# A family of distributions induced by a metric

Tags: statistics

I'm interested in the family of distribution which can be expressed in the following form

$f(x|\mu)=C \exp(-d(x,\mu))$

where $\mu$ is a parameter of the distribution and $d(*,*)$ is a metric. 
Normal distribution and Laplace distribution satisfy this property.
I was wondering if this family has already been studied and what is its name.

Comment: Maybe a more general family is represented by:

$$f(x|\mu,\alpha)=C \exp(-\alpha \cdot d(x,\mu))$$

Comment: @the_candyman - assuming $\alpha \gt 0$ then wouldn't $\alpha\cdot d(x,\mu)$ be another metric?

Comment: @Henry, that's right!

Comment: I was wrong, normal distribution is not in this family.